# Can't switch back to server workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

With VS2013 and TFS2013, I have switched my workspace to a local one, but due to a lack of performance (I have a lot of items in my workspace), I would like to switch back to the server location.

But when I change my settings from this:

[image: Local workspace]

To that:

[image: server workspace]

VS show me the following error:

[image: error]

And show me the form again.

How can I switch back to the server location?

Comment: Is the value for the Server correct?  The actual path to the server?

Comment: yes all seems ok for the server and other informations

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check in or shelve all of your open changes. Then you can completely delete your workspace and create  new server assed one.

I think that ill be easier then trying to debug whatever is going on in there.